# Google omaha compilation error omaha3_idl.tlb

Tags: .net, native

I am trying to compile google Omaha https://github.com/google/omaha.

After configure some enviroment path, i finally receive an error

```
    scons: done reading SConscript files.                         

    scons: Building targets ...

    scons: building associated VariantDir targets: scons-out

    ________Compiling IDL scons-out\dbg-win\obj\goopdate\omaha3_idl.tlb

    scons: *** [scons-out\dbg-win\obj\goopdate\omaha3_idl.tlb] Error 1

    scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

So the error is no descriptive. I do not know what to try.

I try to compile omaha3_idl.idl directly with

```
    midl omaha3_idl.idl
```

And I can generate tlb file.

Do you know how can I test the build? Any suggest of the error?

Thanks,